# Закрытие браузера по умолчанию

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, браузер

Доброе время суток!
Есть приложение, открывающее ссылки по списку. На слабом компе если 10 таких ссылок открыть, то браузер повиснет. В связи с этим я должен закрывать браузер.
Все происходит так:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = str;
proc.Start();
```

где `str` -- какая-то ссылка.
Вопрос заключается в том, что после задержки браузер по умолчанию, в котором открылась ссылка, необходимо закрыть.

В ответ на `proc.Kill()` пишет

> Нет процессов, связанных с этим объектом.

Есть ли иной способ, кроме как лезть в реестр и узнавать оттуда браузер по умолчанию?

**UPD.** Приложение *WindowsFormsApplication*

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b(v=vs.100).aspx   
http://forums.asp.net/t/1153888.aspx?How+to+detect+the+browser+close+event+in+ASP+Net+C+

Comment: Вторая ссылка -- как обнаружить закрытие браузера в ASP, и обе ссылки -- только по ASP. У меня WindowsForms приложение (забыл указать).

Answer (score 2):

Используй [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) для управления конкретным браузером.

Вообще нелогично открывать ссылки в дефаултном браузере, а потом пытаться что-то с ним сделать. Только хром порождает отдельный процесс на вкладку, так что во всех остальных браузерах прибиванием процесса одну вкладку закрыть не удастся.

Comment: И даже Хром давно уже использует 1 процесс для нескольких вкладок.

Answer (score 1):

Ну сразу после запуска процесса дёрнуть имя исполняемого файла из свойств. Найти все процессы запущенные с этого исполняемого файла и замочить их все, мочить в блоках try..catch с пустым catch... 
А может не стоит трогать браузер? Отображать через встроенный WebNavigator и делать с ним что хочешь(вот только он работает на базе ИЕ со всеми вытекающими)

Comment: Дополню: вместо `WebNavigator` можно использовать `Awesomium`, сделанный на базе браузера `Chromium`.